# Datebox, jtsage timeflipbox on mobile - simulate inertia when rolling the date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datebox

I'm using jqueryUI Datebox with jtsage plugin.
My problem is with the timeFlipBox on mobile devices (I'm using phonegap but the problem can be reproduced with any web browser.)
I would like to have an intertia effect when rolling the time.
link : http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/jqueryui/timeflipbox/

On android inertia effect is unabled by default.
On iOS I tried:

```
.ui-datebox-container, .ui-overlay-shadow, .ui-datebox-flipcontent, ul {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Yet there is no inertia effect neither on android nor on iOS.

Where does it come from ?
Is there a workaround ?

Comment: I wasn't aware there actually was a CSS way of doing this.  I've not found a decent way to do it via javascript, but if someone has a link, I'd be very happy to implement this.

Comment: @J.T.Sage It seams to me that the roll is made by scrolling <ul> in .ui-datebox-flipcontent.
Generaly when I set a <div> overflow scroll, there is inertia, so why no inertia in your case ?
Anyway, can you share your solution via javascript ?